# Do while loop And condition not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a while loop and the AND condition is not working correctly

```
For Each y In ws.Range("C1:C" & ws.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row)
    If InStr(y, "Total") > 0 Then
        i = -1
        Do While (InStr(ws.Range("C" & y.Row).Offset(i, 0), Right(y, Len(y) - InStr(y, " "))) = 0 And InStr(ws.Range("C" & y.Row).Offset(i, 0), "%)") = 0)
            i = i - 1
        Loop
    End If
Next y
```

The second instr is not working and I am getting false positives. Basically, the code finds a word starting with total, then it takes the string after the "Total " and looks for that word, but the word should also have "%)" in it

Comment: you know that `.Offset(i, 0)` is moving down one row each time.  also you are including the space in your Instr search with the Right()  so `test` is actually ` test` with a space before.

Comment: Yeah, both factors would not cause a challenge, indeed I am moving backwards, if the space is included it is not a problem as the cell I am looking for would include the space. For some reason the second condition is not kicking in. Even when I do a message box and the while is broken, it comes up as instr(cell,"%)") as zero, which makes no sense

Comment: Please show some test data, current output, and expected output.  It will help us find the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `InStr` function properly.

> Syntax

```
InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
```

Comment: The `[]` makes the first and last optional, so he is using it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I do get confused with instr, and search (the formula), I did use msgboxs to make sure I was using it correctly. Thanks for the advice though